# six.u() un-escaping HTML string

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

Using Python 2.7. As part of a JSON response, an API returns the string:

```
<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>
```

I'm using a library that internally does:

```
six.u(json.dumps(s))
```

`json.dumps()` output is:

```
'"<a href=\\"https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck\\" rel=\\"nofollow\\">TweetDeck</a>"'
```

This output can be decoded correctly with `json.loads`

But the call to `six.u` gives:

```
u'"<a href="https://about.twitter.com/products/tweetdeck" rel="nofollow">TweetDeck</a>"'
```

And attempting to decode this string with `json.loads` throws an error.

```
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 11 - line 1 column 86 (char 10 - 85)
```

Looks like the call to `six.u` un-escaped the `href` value, but i'm not entirely sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`six.u()` is meant for *unicode string literals*, not JSON output. You should not use it to decode the JSON to a Unicode string.

From the [`six.u()` documenation](http://pythonhosted.org/six/#six.u):

> A “fake” unicode literal. **`text` should always be a normal string literal.** In Python 2, `u()` returns unicode, and in Python 3, a string. Also, in Python 2, the string is decoded with the `unicode-escape` codec, which allows unicode escapes to be used in it.

*Emphasis mine*.

Instead, decode the string if using Python 2:

```
json_string = json.dumps(s)
if hasattr(json_string, 'decode'):
    # Python 2; decode to a Unicode value
    json_string = json_string.decode('ascii')
```

or use the `unicode()` function and catch the `NameError` in Python 3:

```
json_string = json.dumps(s)
try:
    # Python 2; decode to a Unicode value from ASCII
    json_string = unicode(json_string)
except NameError:
    # Python 3, already Unicode
    pass
```

or set `ensure_ascii` to `False` when calling `json.dumps()`:

```
json_string = json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This can still return a `str` type in Python 2 though, but only if the input contains nothing but ASCII-only data, so the output can safely be mixed with `unicode` values.

Either way you get consistent values between Python 2 and Python 3; The `six.u()` decode also decodes `\uhhhh` *JSON* Unicode escape sequences to Unicode codepoints, while the Python 3 JSON result would leave those intact. With decoding you'd keep the `\uhhhh` sequences in both Python 2 and 3, with `ensure_ascii` you'd get Unicode codepoints in both.

Since this is a 3rd-party library, I [filed a bug report](https://github.com/jlafon/PynamoDB/issues/61); you cannot really recover from this mistake; you cannot insert extra backslashes up front then remove them afterward as you cannot distinguish those from normal backslashes.

Comment: ``six.u(json.dumps(o))`` is a call made internally in the library i'm using, where ``o`` is just an object I pass in. Any way to pre-process the string to avoid this error?

Comment: @gandu: what library is this? That's *really* a dumb thing they are doing and should be reported as a bug.

Comment: ``pynamodb``: https://github.com/jlafon/PynamoDB/blob/devel/pynamodb/attributes.py#L173

Comment: Thanks Martin! Appreciate it.